# How to Vertical Align an Image on VBSSCRIPT

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

Thanks for the web site and thanks for taking you time to read this.

I created a signature based on a VBS Script i pulled for numerous web   sites online and got the signature almost like i would like it to be, just got a few more tweaks before i stop messing with it. i can´t seem to get the vertical alignment to work. Can you help me out please.

The code is below and the image showing refering to what i need is attached.

1. i need to move the right side image to the a bottom aligned position
2. i need to remove the space i have between the blue bar and the table  above.

Appriciate the help, i am not a programmer just trying to do my best to automate signatures in outlook.

```
 On Error Resume Next
'Option Explicit

Dim objSysInfo,strUser,objUser,strName,strMail,strWebAddr,strCompany,strDepartment,strStreetAddr,strHomePhone,strIpPhone,strMobile
Dim objWord,objDoc,objSelection,objEmailOptions,objSignatureObject,objSignatureEntries,objLink,strlogoATL,strlogoMA,strlogoBAR
Dim objRange,objTable

Set objSysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
strUser = objSysInfo.UserName
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strUser)

strName = objUser.FirstName &" "& objUser.LastName
strMail = objuser.mail
strWebAddr = objuser.wWWHomePage
strCompany = objuser.Company
strDepartment = objUser.Department
strStreetAddr = objuser.streetaddress
strHomePhone =  objuser.HomePhone
strIpPhone = objuser.ipPhone
strMobile = objuser.Mobile

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

objSelection.Style = "No Spacing"
Set objEmailOptions = objWord.EmailOptions
Set objSignatureObject = objEmailOptions.EmailSignature
Set objSignatureEntries = objSignatureObject.EmailSignatureEntries

'Name of Staff
objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Size = "10"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(91,91,91)
objSelection.TypeText strName
objSelection.TypeText(Chr(11))

objSelection.TypeParagraph()

'Mail
objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Size = "8"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(91,91,91)
Set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range, "mailto: " & strMail, , , strMail) 
objSelection.TypeText(Chr(11))

'Tel
objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Size = "8"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(91,91,91)
objSelection.TypeText "Ext : "& strIpPhone & "   " & " "& chr(124) & "   Telem" & Chr(243) & "vel : " & strMobile
objSelection.TypeText(Chr(11))

objSelection.TypeParagraph()


'Department
objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Size = "8"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(0,153,181)
objSelection.TypeText strDepartment
objSelection.TypeText(Chr(11))

'Address
objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Size = "8"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(0,153,181)
objSelection.TypeText strStreetAddr
objSelection.TypeText(Chr(11))

objSelection.TypeParagraph()

'Company Contact details
objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(0,153,181)
objSelection.TypeText "Tel : "& strHomePhone & "    " & chr(124) & "   "

'Web
objSelection.Font.Name = "Verdana"
objSelection.Font.Color = RGB(0,153,181)
set objLink = objSelection.Hyperlinks.Add(objSelection.Range,strWebAddr)


strlogoATL="c:\Utils\Assinatura\ins_atl.jpg"
strlogoMA="c:\Utils\Assinatura\ins_ma.jpg"
strlogoBAR="c:\Utils\Assinatura\ins_bar.jpg"

Set objRange = objSelection.Range
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 1, 2
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(1)
objTable.leftpadding = 0
objTable.rightpadding = 0

objTable.Columns(1).Width = objWord.CentimetersToPoints(12.00)
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strlogoATL)

objTable.Columns(2).Width = objWord.CentimetersToPoints(12.00)
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalCenter
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strlogoMA)

objSelection.EndKey 6
objSelection.TypeParagraph()

Set objRange = objSelection.Range
objDoc.Tables.Add objRange, 1, 1
Set objTable = objDoc.Tables(2)
objTable.leftpadding = 0
objTable.rightpadding = 0

objTable.Columns(1).Width = objWord.CentimetersToPoints(24.00)
objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strlogoBAR)

objSelection.EndKey 6

objSelection.TypeParagraph()

Set objSelection = objDoc.Range()

objSignatureEntries.Add "ATLANTICO", objSelection
objSignatureObject.NewMessageSignature = "ATLANTICO"
objSignatureObject.ReplyMessageSignature = "ATLANTICO"
objDoc.Saved = True
objWord.Quit

wscript.echo "Uma nova assinatura foi aplicada ao seu Outlook!"
```

Picture of problem shown below

[image]

Comment: `Range.VerticalAlignment = wdCellAlignVerticalBottom`?

Comment: Lankymart, did not work, tried that before, i tried a few "wdCellAlignVerticalBottom" variations... none seem to work... any other ideias?

Comment: Well that is what they are there for so if they don't work then something else is causing it, padding, line spacing for example.

Comment: First try to solve in the Word UI, maybe with the assistance of an end-user group. Once you discover what works, you can record a macro to get the basic syntax and incorporate that into your code.

Comment: @Lankymart - As i said i am not a programmer, not sure what i need to do really or change, thanks anyways.

Comment: @Cindy - in word UI i can move and place it on the bottom as i would like, i also can remove the space... but how to see the code behind it?

Comment: Did you try recording a macro while performing the actions, as I suggested? There's no way that we can tell you what you have to do - we don't have (or want) the document. You have to provide, at the very least, this basic research information.